# Reduce Image size in php while uploading

Tags: php, image, size, reduce

**PHP** - I am using this code to upload image file but i don't how to reduce the image file size but quality should be maintain .

```
$todir = 'members/'.$_SESSION[' valid_user '].'/';
$RandomNum   = rand(0, 9999999999);
$info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['Image']['name']) ); // whats the extension of the file
 if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['Image']['name']-$RandomNum) ) )
 {
 $handle= 'members/'.$_SESSION[' valid_user '].'/'.basename($_FILES['Image']['name']-$RandomNum);
 echo 'uploaded';
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean that quality should maintain? If you reduce the size, you will lose some information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ImageMagick to bring your images down to more appropriate sizes? (http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
     $name = "";
     $type = "";
     $size = "";
     $error = "";
     function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {
        $info = getimagesize($source_url);
        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
        imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
        return $destination_url; 
    } 

    if ($_POST) {
       if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
           $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];           
       } else if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")){
            $url = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $filename = compress_image($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $url, 30);
            $buffer = file_get_contents($url);                             
        }else {
            $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png";                   
        }
    }

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Php code compress the image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="message">
            <?php if($_POST){ if ($error) { ?>
            <label class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></label>
                <?php } } ?>
        </div>
        <legend>Upload Image:</legend>
        <form action="" name="myform" id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                
            <label>Upload:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>          
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn-success"/>                    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.